# What is/does `bool c2s(int)` in Hoard?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, hoard

In the [source of geometricsizeclass.cpp](https://github.com/emeryberger/Hoard/blob/master/src/include/hoard/geometricsizeclass.cpp) of [Hoard (the memory allocator)](http://hoard.org/) there a not defined function `bool c2s(int)`.

What is it, what does it do ?

I'm trying to compile hoard as a library in VS2019, ignoring the Makefile.

Comment: It [seems pretty defined to me](https://github.com/emeryberger/Hoard/blob/master/src/include/hoard/geometricsizeclass.h#L126-L132).

Comment: Why is this tagged C when your code is written in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [there](https://github.com/emeryberger/Hoard/blob/87e966f8e5f1a66501851199caeacf0ee4f59339/src/include/hoard/geometricsizeclass.h#L127) in the header file:

```
/// Quickly compute the maximum size for a given size class.
static unsigned long c2s (int cl) {
  static size_t sizes[NUM_SIZECLASSES];
  static bool init = createTable ((size_t *) sizes);
  init = init;
  return sizes[cl];
}
```